# How to call method of other object in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python, and I have small problem, I have two classes, and it wrotes this : set_gyro_angle() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) how can I call **set_gyro_angle()** method from Machine method?

```
class Gyro(object):
    """gyroskop senzor"""
    def __init__(self,gyro_start_angle = 0):
        self.gyro_angle = 0 
    def get_gyro_angle():
        return self.gyro_angle
    def set_gyro_angle(angle):
        self.gyro_angle = angle
        return 0

class Maschine(object):
    def __init__(self, state = "normal",length = 10,width = 15):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.gyro = Gyro()
    def setPoint(self,alpha):
        self.gyro.set_gyro_angle(alpha)
        return 0
```

Main:

```
maschine  = Maschine()
maschine.setPoint()
```

Comment: Please correct the class name `Maschine()`. should not it be only  `Machine()`. It seems you have typo there

Comment: thank you, it was a typo

Comment: @MaNKuR You can't stand it, hahahah

Comment: Its individual choice. I accepted it lets see others ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an instance method, you need to add an extra argument that will be a pointer to your instance. Usually it's `self`:

```
class Gyro(object):
    """gyroskop senzor"""
    def __init__(self,gyro_start_angle = 0):
        self.gyro_angle = 0 
    def get_gyro_angle(self):
        return self.gyro_angle
    def set_gyro_angle(self, angle):
        self.gyro_angle = angle
        return 0
```

And i think you want `setPoint` to be like this:

```
def setPoint(self, alpha):
    self.gyro.set_gyro_angle(alpha)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of your instance methods should have another parameter, `self`, before the others; this is the instance itself, and is passed automatically:

```
def set_gyro_angle(self, angle):
```

Alternatively, skip the setter:

```
self.gyro.gyro_angle = alpha
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Machine.gyro.set_gyro_angle(45)
```

However you need to fix your code by adding the self parameter as the first parameter of your class methods.